# SQL Server - insert into, return the id and update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one for staging and one for production. Staging with the columns `name`, `phone`, and `bd_id` and the production databases has columns `id`, `name`, and `phone`.

I have several rows of data in the staging table and I want to insert them all in the production database and return the `id` of the production row to update the column `bd_id` of the staging table.

If I insert them one by one, I can do it, by putting at the end of the insert into the `SET @bd_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY ()`, but is there a way to do this, but inserting several rows at the same time?

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL

Comment: Use the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: but the output clause isnt the same? just for one row at the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
declare @ids table (int id, name varchar(255), phone varchar(255));

insert into production (name, phone)
    output id, name, phone into @ids
    select name, phone
    from staging s;

update s
    set s.b_id = i.id
    from staging s join
         @ids i
         on s.name = i.name and s.phone = i.phone;
```

This assumes that `name`/`phone` is unique on the `staging` table.